# threading program in C++ not faster

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program which reads the file line by line and then stores each possible substring of length 50 in a hash table along with its frequency. I tried to use threads in my program so that it will read 5 lines and then use five different threads to do the processing. The processing involves reading each substring of that line and putting them into hash map with frequency. But it seems there is something wrong which I could not figure out for which the program is not faster then the serial approach. Also, for large input file it is aborted. Here is the piece of code I am using

```
unordered_map<string, int> m;
mutex mtx;

    void parseLine(char *line, int subLen){
        int no_substr = strlen(line) - subLen;
        for(int i = 0; i <= no_substr; i++) {
            char *subStr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)* subLen + 1);
            strncpy(subStr, line+i, subLen);
            subStr[subLen]='\0';
            mtx.lock();
            string s(subStr);
            if(m.find(s) != m.end()) m[s]++;
            else {
                  pair<string, int> ret(s, 1);
                  m.insert(ret);
            }
            mtx.unlock();    
        }
    }


    int main(){    

        char **Array = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_thread +1); 
        int num = 0;

        while (NOT END OF FILE) {
            if(num < num_th) {
                 if(num == 0) 
                    for(int x = 0; x < num_th; x++) 
                       Array[x] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(line)+1);
                 strcpy(Array[num], line);
                 num++;
              }
              else {
                 vector<thread> threads;
                 for(int i = 0; i < num_th; i++) {
                    threads.push_back(thread(parseLine, Array[i]);
                 }
                 for(int i = 0; i < num_th; i++){
                    if(threads[i].joinable()) {
                      threads[i].join();
                    }
                 }
                 for(int x = 0; x < num_th; x++) free(seqArray[x]);
                 num = 0;
              }
            } 
    }
```

Comment: How many cores can you actually address on your target machine?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines and post a [MCVE].

Comment: For one -- the task of parsing the line probably is probably not much more than the task of creating the thread, and secondly, you have a single `mutex mtx` which every thread is waiting on making only one thread running at any given time.

Comment: The reason I am using single `mutex` to avoid overwriting the count of substrings

Comment: Please read [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html). In particular the table with approximate timings for various operations.

Comment: On my ubuntu 15.10 (64), g++ v5.2.1, I measure method invocation to be 1000 times faster than thread context switch.  (9 ns  -- 12000 ns).  In your design with threads, can you estimate how many thread switches occur?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I am not sure how many thread switches will occur. The number of lines in an input line can be one million. and length of each line is 100~150.

Comment: Also note: you never free `subStr`, which may be the cause of your abort.

Answer (score 3):

It's a myth that just by the virtue of using threads, the end result must be faster. In general, in order to take advantage of multithreading, two conditions must be met(*):

1) You actually have to have sufficient physical CPU cores, that can run the threads at the same time.

2) The threads have independent tasks to do, that they can do on their own.

From a cursory examination of the shown code, it seems to fail on the second part. It seems to me that, most of the time all of these threads will be fighting each other in order to acquire the same mutex. There's little to be gained from multithreading, in this situation.

(*) Of course, you don't always use threads for purely performance reasons. Multithreading also comes in useful in many other situations too, for example, in a program with a GUI, having a separate thread updating the GUI helps the UI working even while the main execution thread is chewing on something, for a while...

Comment: and (3) the task need to be sufficiently large compared to the overhead of creating and delegating the work to threads....